# Issues with obfuscation of Android library project using Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, deobfuscation, android-proguard

When applying Proguard on Android library project there are well known considerations and issues. Usually the basic logic is:

1. Use correct code guidelines and put only the public API as `public foo()...`
2. Use well known Proguard rules which are from the kind "obfuscate all privates"

These ([with other known library Proguard rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120565/obfuscating-android-library-project-source-code-with-proguard)) will ensure usually a desired result.

The hack is that: I have a large (and complex in means of dependencies and use of third party API's & SDK's) library project, historically not written with good coding guidelines. So the trivial solution is to go class by class, and prepare some kind of custom `-keep` rule for each. This is quite not feasible task. Is there another alternative in such cases? The target is obfuscation not using Proguard so i'm open to use alternatives.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no strict separation between public (the methods you want to expose in your api) and the private methods?

Comment: @Bas exactly and I think there are more issues and I gave the `public` Vs `private` just as simple example.