# Add jar file path added in library project in PROGUARD

Tags: android, proguard

I have started including proguard in my project. But getting few warning. I am able to eliminate the warning by adding `-dontwarn com.google.**`. in proguard.cfg file. Every thing is okk, but I want to eliminate the `-dontwarn` command entirely from my project. After some investigation I found out these warning is there because I have added a jar in my library project. Now I have few questions here.

1) Do I need to add anything in my project properties for progurad to work on my library project. And also doesn't add any warning
(As per my research I dont need to I guess. Refer to [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982344/is-proguard-cfg-needed-for-library-projects))

2) Since my **guava.jar** is added in my library project, Do I need to some command in my application `proguard.cfg` file to add library path like **-libraryjars**. If yes, how do I add the -libraryjars . I am talking about path  at this instance. What path should I include or whats the syntax of adding path of the jar which is there in my library project?

Just for refrence I am adding error log.

```
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Equivalences$Impl$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Function: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Function: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions$ConstantFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions$ConstantFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions$ConstantFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions$ForMapWithDefault: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions$ForMapWithDefault: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions$FunctionComposition: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions$FunctionForMapNoDefault: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Functions$PredicateFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Joiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Joiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Joiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Joiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Joiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Joiner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Objects$ToStringHelper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Objects$ToStringHelper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.PairwiseEquivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.PairwiseEquivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.PairwiseEquivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.PairwiseEquivalence: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Platform: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Preconditions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
[2014-12-11 18:00:26 - MyProject] Warning: com.google.common.base.Preconditions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
 more few hundred lines of error.
```

Can anybody help me in this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

The warnings are harmless in this case: the missing class is not necessary for the correct processing or execution of your code. You can either add the jar that contains javax.annotation.Nullable as a dependency in your project, or you can suppress the warnings. This works indeed:

```
-dontwarn com.google.**
```

Alternatively, this is slightly more succinct:

```
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
```

Comment: That simply mean that I have to put this commands. Also with above code I am able to compile the code but while serilizer.read() command is executing its gives me exception `Constructor not matched`. Any idea or suggestion why its happening. Refer to the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646554/constructor-not-matched-for-class-proguard